# PDO insert query won't insert data in my database

Tags: php, pdo, insert

I need to insert ratings into my database, so i tried with this link set:

```
<?php foreach (range(1, 5) as $ocena) { ?>
<a href="ocena.php?clanak=<?php echo $clanci['id'];?>&ocena=<?php echo      $ocena; ?>"><?php echo $ocena; ?></a>
<?php } ?>

And in my ocena.php i have $_get method to retrive values and store it in database:

<?php

include_once 'includes/konekcija.php';

if (isset($_GET['clanak'], $_GET['ocena'])) {
    $clanak = $_GET['clanak'];
    $ocena = $_GET['ocena'];

    if (in_array($ocena, [1,2,3,4,5])) {
         $niz = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id FROM clanci WHERE id =:id");
         $niz->bindParam(":id", $clanak);
         $niz->execute();
         $red = $niz->fetch();

        if ($red) {
            $upit = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO ocene (clanak, ocena) VALUES (?, ?)");
            $upit->bindValue(1, $clanak);
            $upit->bindValue(2, $ocene);
            $upit->execute();

            header('Location: clanak.php?id=' .$clanak);
        } else {
            echo 'Nesto nije u redu.';
        }
    }
}
```

So it relocate and everything seems to be fine, but when i check out my database the result was now inserted. What am I not seeing?

Comment: Have you treid run manually the insert sql to test it?

Comment: You have a typo -> `$ocene` -> `$upit->bindValue(2, $ocene);`. Shouldn't this be `$upit->bindValue(2, $ocena);`?